# Many-to-many with extra columns + getting unique objects

Tags: java, hibernate

Let's say we have 3 Tables:

Employee (id), Proj_emp(employee_id, project_id), Project(id)

and we use solution described here:

[**Mapping a Join Table with Additional Columns**](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Mapping_a_Join_Table_with_Additional_Columns), 
to map these tables in Hibernate.

What is the best way to get all projects from Employee class? Should I just create a method that iterates over `List<ProjectAssociation> projects` and gets unique Projects from it?

Or is there a better way using hibernate mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach to follow in this case is to use [**Java Set**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of `List<E>` because it doesn't allow duplicates, so you will only have unique results.

And then you will just need to use the getter of your object to get those unique results:

```
Set<ProjectAssociation> projects;
public Set<ProjectAssociation> getProjects{
    return this.projects;
}
```